# Empty for loop only used for counting

Tags: c++, string, loops

I was writing a method to read a string and discard all characters up until it finds a white space character. I came up with this:

```
void Utility::TrimToWhiteSpace( std::string& str )
{
    size_t  i = 0;
    for( ; i < str.size() && !std::isspace( str[i], "C" ); i++ ){}
    str.erase( 0, i );
}
```

I only really need this loop for counting, but it seems odd to leave it blank. Will this cause any issues with optimisation for example?

Comment: Check the output and see for yourself.

Comment: Wouldn't a `while` loop with the `i++` within the loop be more natural in this case?

Comment: If the loop has observable behaviour (it does), and your code does not have undefined behaviour, optimizations should not change anything. But you can use `std::find_if`.

Comment: @Heavy It doesn't do the same thing.

Comment: @Iridium It would be my personal preference, but it's really a question of style.  I've seen a lot of code which uses the `for` in this case as well.

Comment: @JamesKanze But a simple `while` would still be clearer if you go for a simple `for`.

Comment: @Mayerz It's a question of style.  As I said, I personally would use a `while` in this case.  But it's a personal style preference, not something absolute.  Both are perfectly clear.

Comment: @JamesKanze Question of style yes, but its less characters also, and isn't a while more optimized than a for? I know this is c++ but hey always forbidden for loops in C code at school, and I kept the habbit to use while for simple loops (no iterators or tmp var of course)

Comment: @Mayerz A lot of these "X is faster than Y" type arguments are irrelevant for any modern optimizing compiler, they likely result in identical generated code here. Even if optimizations did affect the code generated, given the complexity of the optimizations that such compilers may apply and the many subtleties that determine the cases in which it can and cannot apply them, it's unlikely that such broad statements as to the speed of one construct over another are possible.

Comment: @Mayerz A `for` loop is formally defined in terms of `while`, so the compiler should generate exactly the same code in both cases.  As for "forbidding for" in school: I have seem some horrible abuse of `for` at times.  But if we forbid everything that has been abused in C++, there won't be any language left.  In this precise example, I have no problem with the `for`; any difference between it and `while` is purely esthetic and personal preferences.

Comment: Ok @JamesKanze thanks for taking time to explain

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Such "empty" loops are frequent when doing look-up; there's no
real problem with them.  Although many people, myself included,
would prefer a `while` in this case, the `for` as you've written
it is quite acceptable, and should cause no problems.

Of course, in idiomatic C++, you'd use `std::remove` and
`std::find_if`, rather than a hand written loop:

```
str.remove(
    std::find_if( str.begin(), str.end(), []( char ch ) { return !std::isspace( ch, "C" ); } ),
    str.end() );
```

Personnally, I'd also avoid the two parameter form of
`std::isspace` except in isolated instances.  In this case,
something more along the lines of:

```
static std::locale const cLocale( "C" );    //  Define locale to ensure lifetime.
static std::ctype<char> const& cType( std::use_facet<std::codecvt<char>>( cLocale ) );
str.remove(
    std::find_if( str.begin(), str.end(), [&]( char ch) { return !cType.is( std::ctype_base::space, ch ); } ),
    str.end() );
```

Or if you're doing any amount of text processing:

```
template <std::ctype_base::mask mask>
class Is
{
    std::locale myCopyToEnsureLifetime;
    std::ctype<char> const* myCType;
public:
    Is( std::locale const& locale = std::locale() )
        : myCopyToEnsureLifetime( locale )
        , myCType( &std::use_facet<std::codecvt<char>>( myCopyToEnsureLifetime )
    {
    }
    bool operator()( char ch ) const
    {
        return myCType->is( mask, ch );
    }
};

template <std::ctype_base::mask mask>
class IsNot
{
    std::locale myCopyToEnsureLifetime;
    std::ctype<char> const* myCType;
public:
    Is( std::locale const& locale = std::locale() )
        : myCopyToEnsureLifetime( locale )
        , myCType( &std::use_facet<std::codecvt<char>>( myCopyToEnsureLifetime )
    {
    }
    bool operator()( char ch ) const
    {
        return !myCType->is( mask, ch );
    }
};

typedef Is<std::ctype_base::space> IsSpace;
typedef IsNot<std::ctype_base::space> IsNotSpace;
//  And so on...
```

Using `std::locale` directly can be a bit verbose, and it's
worth wrapping it once with a more reasonable interface in your
toolkit, and systematically using the wrappers.